Azure issues with netty transitive dependency (NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/resolver/AddressResolverGroup)
I have a transitive dependency issue with Azure and its use of Netty.
Summary of the tree:
Project A > depends on custom library B > depends on Azure > depends on Netty.
Library B is fine (eg. unit/integration tests no problem), while Project A complains of Netty being not found.
For context — here is library B pom.xml snippet with Azure dependency versions:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

Error experienced when running project A
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/resolver/AddressResolverGroup
        at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClientProvider.createInstance(NettyAsyncHttpClientProvider.java:64) ~[azure-core-http-netty-1.15.3.jar:1.15.3]
        at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClientProvider.createInstance(NettyAsyncHttpClientProvider.java:70) ~[azure-core-http-netty-1.15.3.jar:1.15.3]
        at com.azure.core.implementation.http.HttpClientProviders.lambda$createInstance$0(HttpClientProviders.java:58) ~[azure-core-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
        at com.azure.core.implementation.util.Providers.create(Providers.java:119) ~[azure-core-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
        at com.azure.core.implementation.http.HttpClientProviders.createInstance(HttpClientProviders.java:58) ~[azure-core-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
        at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.createDefault(HttpClient.java:61) ~[azure-core-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
        at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.createDefault(HttpClient.java:51) ~[azure-core-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
        at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipelineBuilder.build(HttpPipelineBuilder.java:88) ~[azure-core-1.51.0.jar:1.51.0]
        at com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder.buildInnerClient(SecretClientBuilder.java:247) ~[azure-security-keyvault-secrets-4.8.6.jar:4.8.6]
        at com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder.buildClient(SecretClientBuilder.java:158) ~[azure-security-keyvault-secrets-4.8.6.jar:4.8.6]

I'm curious why this would happen, I shouldn't need to manually include Netty in Project A, right?! Or Azure for that matter.
Seeking advice / solutions.

FYI i found additional recommendations here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#im-getting-a-nosuchmethoderror-or-noclassdeffounderror

I think* I have a workaround — but I still don't see why this should be needed
I added the Azure dependencies to "project A":
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Originally this put me into new dependency conflict issues, what helped is to include the Bill of Materials as per Azure docs recommendation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/get-started-maven#add-azure-sdk-for-java-to-an-existing-project
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-sdk-bom</artifactId>
      <version>{bom_version_to_target}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

*still attempting to verify, but this has resolved the immediate NoClassDefFoundError error
